# nib to storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, nib

I am using Apple's app calculator but I need to put it into a `storyboard` not in a `xib` file.  Can some one walk me through how to change it?

The code from apples app is as follows:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

   // Override point for customization after application launch
   CalcViewController *_calcViewController = [[CalcViewController alloc]        initWithNibName:@"CalcView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   self.calcViewController = _calcViewController;
   [window addSubview:[calcViewCont``roller view]];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The `storyboard` I want to place it into is called `SecondViewController`.

Can some one help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Navigator click on your project name, then select your app Target, now add your storyboard name as Main Storyboard, make sure Main Interface is blank.

Now in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` just remove everything you have there in that method.